# How to know all subclasses of base class in Angular

Tags: angular, oop, data-structures, abstract-class, subclass

```
abstract class Item {
  private name: string;
  private description: string;

constructor(name: string,description:string) {
      this.name = name;
      this.description = description;
    }
}


 class Car extends Item {

 constructor(name: string,description:string) {
     super(name,description);
  }
}
           // Subclass class 
   class Bike extends Item {

 constructor(name: string,description:string) {
     super(name,description);
  }
}

 class Bird extends Item {

 constructor(name: string,description:string) {
     super(name,description);
  }
}
```

Please note that Item is an abstract class so we can not create an object of the Item class.
I want to get a result something like this.

"Base class: Item"

"SubClasses: Bike, Bird, Car"

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt you can. It's not something that object oriented languages tend to be able to do, for the simple reason that there's no real way of knowing (especially since the child classes may not even be loaded into the runtime environment at the time you're looking. They may not even exist on the machine where the runtime is operating).

Comment: can we know the base class from the subclass if we have an object is initiated?

Comment: @NeoMurphy not sure about Angular, but in other OO languages you can.